# How can I properly recurse this object list?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a list of Room objects that I would like to set up a recursive function to assign some values to. Here are the relevant properties of the Room object:

```
class Room
{
    int Room_Number;
    string N;
    string S;
    string E;
    string W;
    int X;
    int Y;
    int Z;
    bool isRecursed;
}
```

For each Room object, if the relevant exit (N, S, E, W) goes to another room, that string value will be the Room_Number of the adjoining room. If there is no exit in that direction, the value will be "0". I also have a function GetChildren(Room room). This function returns a list of all of the valid adjoining rooms that have yet to be recursed and also sets their X,Y,Z properties based on the cardinal direction converted to a Cartesian plane (eg: room.N != "0" add the child room to the list and increment the Y value by 1, room.S != "0" and subtract the Y value by 1, etc.) For some reason, my recursion function never seems to end. It will continue to cycle through rooms for what appears to be an infinite amount of time and never completes. Here is the recursion function:

```
void RecurseRoom(Room r)
{
    r.isRecursed = true;
    foreach(Room child in GetChildren(r))
    {
        RecurseRoom(r);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can define a start room and give it the initial (X,Y,Z) = (0,0,0) then recurse all child rooms until an entire map is complete? Any help or pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You set `r.isRecursed` but you never do a check for if it's true or false. Try adding one of those checks in and put the `foreach()` in there

Comment: Do a search for Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My function GetChildren(Room r) only returns the child rooms who have not been recursed, shouldn't that function the same?

Comment: @jdweng it's more like a recursive BFS

Comment: It is more like a graph than a tree.  Should be Dijkstra's.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent infinite recursion, you need to check `r.isRecursed`, eg:

```
void RecurseRoom(Room r)
{
    if(r.isRecursed) return;
    r.isRecursed = true;
    foreach(Room child in GetChildren(r))
    {
        RecurseRoom(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Props to @Aaron who posted his answer as a comment as I was typing this

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My function GetChildren(Room r) only returns the child rooms who have not been recursed, shouldn't that function the same?